# Excel formula for selecting "n" rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in cell A1:A100. Say in cell B1 I have a value 10 (this 10 can potentially change to any other number less than 100). I am trying to select A1 to as many rows as is stated in cell B1. So when cell B1 has a value of 10 I want to select A1:A10. If cell B1 has 50 I want to select A1:A50.

I want to perform this operation in excel (not VBA). The data I select will be passed onto some other excel function. Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: If you can do it in one step, like this and MacroMarc's answer, then MacroMarc's is probably preferable because if avoids `INDIRECT`. If you truly need the range created in an intermediate cell, then I think you are stuck with using `INDIRECT`, but with more complications than @pnuts comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`=SUM(A1:INDEX($A$1:$A$100, $B$1, 1))`

This is an example of how you could do it...

Comment: +1. The more answers of this nature that are published, the more chance that the average user of Excel is guided down the correct path of using INDEX in such constructions, as opposed to down the (unfortunately) numerous paths which promote the use of inferior OFFSET or INDIRECT set-ups.

Answer (score 0):

if your data is fairly static and will always have only 100 rows, you can use the MacroMarc answer. If your data is dynamic and the number of rows will change ad hoc, the simplest solutions are OFFSET or INDIRECT. For one simple calculation like this, the overhead is insignificant.

If you want to make a copy of the selected data, OFFSET is the easiest to maintain, ie to update when you come back to it a year later.

=OFFSET(A1,0,0,MIN(B1,MAX(ROW(A1#))),1)